# What is the difference between Objects, Object Literals and Template Literals in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I've started just a while back with javascript but feel like a bit of confusion with drawing a clear line of distinction between these 3 topics in JS. Plz provide some clear view.

Comment: [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) are created in the memory, [Object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) is just a way to create an object, [Template Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) is a string which can contain embedded expressions. You could have found all these by a simple search using your favorite searching engine, but there you go ...

Comment: Object = anything that's an object. Object literal = specifically *initialisers* for plain JS object that look like this `{ keyString: "some value", keyNumber: 42}`. Template literals = nothing related to the other two - it's a string initialiser that allows more advanced syntax for string interpolation, evaluation, and building. It's denoted by backticks `\`this is a template literal\``

Answer (score 1):

ELIN (explain like I'm noob)

Objects -> Hashmaps (keys are strings, values are anything)
Template Literals -> New form of passing multiline strings with inline computation.

examples:

```js
const x = 'world';
console.log(`Hello ${x}`) // will print Hello world
```

Template literals can be passed as complex information into functions, with a special syntax:

```js
myFunction`Hello, ${x}`;
```

This will execute myFunction with multiple arguments. The first one will be the non-computed strings, separated by those computed expressions as an array. The rest of the arguments will the computed values.

```js
const x = 'World';
const answer = 42;
console.log`Hello, ${x} the answer is ${answer}`;

/*
[Arguments] {
  '0': [ 'Hello, ', ', the answer is ', '' ],
  '1': 'World',
  '2': 42
}
*/
```